# Efficient way of creating a permutated 2D array with a range of integers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, permutation

I'm trying to find an efficient way to generate a set of x-y coordinates that identifies every position in a square lattice, such that, if the lattice is made up of `NxN` grids, where

```
N = 100; x = range(N)
```

I want to compute a set of arrays such as `array([[0,0], [0,1], [0,2] ..[0,100], [1,0], [1,1], [1,2], ..[1,100], ...[100,0], [100,1], [100,2], ..[100,100]])`. The ordering does not matter. So far I've tried using `itertools.product(x, repeat=2)`, however, the output itertools object is not easy to convert to the above 2D array. Any suggestion would really helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by order does not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A numpy solution could be :

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,100), np.arange(0,100))
result = np.vstack((Y.ravel(), X.ravel())).T
result
# array([[ 0,  0],
#        [ 0,  1],
#        [ 0,  2],
#           ...,
```

Which seems significantly faster than the python way :

```
In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0,100), np.arange(0,100))
   ...: result = np.vstack((Y.ravel(), X.ravel())).T
   ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 109 µs per loop

In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: N = 100
   ...: result = np.array([[x, y] for x in range(N) for y in range(N)])
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.54 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit result = list(itertools.product(range(100),repeat=2))
1000 loops, best of 3: 521 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `N = 100; result = [[x, y] for x in range(N) for y in range(N)]`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think you nailed it,  All you need to do is convert the iterator to a list, which is trivial:

```
y = list(itertools.product(x,repeat=2))
```

Answer (score 1):

ever faster when minimizing copies:

```
def matnp(n):    
    a=np.arange(n)
    b=np.empty((2*n,n),a.dtype)
    b[:n]=np.tile(a,n).reshape(n,n)
    b[n:]=b[:n].T    
    return b.reshape(2,n*n).T
```

test:

```
In [11]: %timeit matnp(101)
10000 loops, best of 3: 54 µs per loop
```

and Numba :

```
from numba import jit
@jit
def matnb(n):
    a=np.empty((n*n,2),np.int)
    k=0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            a[k]=i,j
            k=k+1
    return a
```

test :

```
In [15]: %timeit matnb(101)
10000 loops, best of 3: 31.9 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = np.arange(101)
coords = np.transpose([np.repeat(arr, arr.size),np.tile(arr, arr.size)])

print(coords)
```